# SQL Query Adding All Customers even if they don't have any sales

Tags: sql

Below is my relatively simple sales query but I want it to pick up all of my dealers, not just the dealers that have sales.  Is this possible?

```
SELECT dbo.tblDealer.DealerID, Firstname, LastName,
SUM(dbo.tblOrderDetail.PSVAmount) AS "PSV", 
SUM(dbo.tblOrderDetail.UplineVolume) AS "Upline",
SUM(dbo.tblOrderDetail.LineTotal) AS "Product Total"
FROM tblOrderDetail 
inner join tblOrder 
on dbo.tblOrderDetail.OrderID = dbo.tblOrder.OrderID 
inner join tblDealership on dbo.tblOrder.DealershipID = dbo.tblDealership.DealershipID 
inner join tblDealer on dbo.tblDealership.DealerID = dbo.tblDealer.DealerID
where orderDate between '3/01/12' and '3/21/12 23:59:59'
and dbo.tbldealer.active = -1

GROUP BY dbo.tblDealer.DealerID, Firstname, LastName
```

Comment: See Jeff Atwood's [Visual explanation of SQL JOINs](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) - very helpful

Answer (score 3):

You should change the order of your joins, and do an `outer join` instead of an `inner join`:

```
SELECT dbo.tblDealer.DealerID, Firstname, LastName,
SUM(dbo.tblOrderDetail.PSVAmount) AS "PSV", 
SUM(dbo.tblOrderDetail.UplineVolume) AS "Upline",
SUM(dbo.tblOrderDetail.LineTotal) AS "Product Total"
FROM tblDealer
inner join tblDealership
on dbo.tblDealership.DealerID = dbo.tblDealer.DealerID
left join tblOrder 
on dbo.tblOrderDetail.OrderID = dbo.tblOrder.OrderID AND orderDate between '3/01/12' and '3/21/12 23:59:59'
left join tblOrder 
on dbo.tblOrderDetail.OrderID = dbo.tblOrder.OrderID 
where dbo.tbldealer.active = -1
GROUP BY dbo.tblDealer.DealerID, Firstname, LastName
```